# Como Hago Esto En Un Solo Select de MSSQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

He simplificado el ejemplo en un select sencillo, mi select real tiene 300 líneas, por eso me gustaría saber si este filtro lo puedo poner en un solo select.
Cuando @idAgente=0 no necesito el AND, pero cuando va un @idAgente >=1 si necesito hacer el filtro.

```
if @idAgente=0
begin
select *
from jtable
where fecha between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30'
    end
else
    begin
select *
from jtable
where fecha between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30'
and idAgente=@idAgente
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente algo así:

```
select *
       from jtable
       where fecha between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30'
             and (@idAgente=0 or idAgente=@idAgente)
```

Lo que sí, tienes que tener en cuenta que este tipo de consulta, tiene dos "modalidades" totalmente diferentes, lo cual puede ser una fuente de problemas para el motor a la hora de optimizarla, en el contexto de un SP se puede producir algo que se conoce como ["parameter sniffing"](https://www.gpsos.es/2020/05/parameter-sniffing-en-sql-server/), que de forma simple, podríamos decir, que el SP queda optimizado para un cierto parámetro o conjunto de estos, pero termina siendo totalmente ineficiente, cuando se lo invoca con otros filtros.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. Si estoy de acuerdo con el parámetro @idAgente =0 el procedimiento demora mayor tiempo en ejecutarse dado que retorna todos los Agentes. Pero otra forma sería hacer 2 procedimientos uno general  y otro por Agente, que recomiendas?

Comment: La idea de tener 2 Sp es lo ideal, al menos desde el punto de vista de las eventuales optimizaciones que haga el motor, claro que no hay nada más cómodo y mantenible que resolver todo en una sola consulta.